# Minimal root of $f(x)$ mod $p$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible integral polynomial with degree $\text{deg}[f]$. If $p|f(x)$ for some $x$, then denote by $S(p)$ the smallest positive number $x_0$ such that $p | f(x_0)$.

Do there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $$ S(p) < cp^{\frac{2}{\text{deg}[f]}} \, ,$$ for some constant $0<c<0.5$ ?

What happens if we replace $2$ by another constant $d$?

Comment: This is known for polynomials of degree $2$ by work of Duke, Friedlander, and Iwaniec, under some technical conditions, later removed by Arpad Toth.  Even with an exponent $1$ and arbitrarily small constant $c$, it is probably open with larger degree polynomials.